# JW Player 6 working on local server but not on live server

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm using jw player to stream live rtmp streams off edgecast. The system works fine on my local server (wamp) but when I take the exact same code and put it on the (lamp) live server the rtmp streams don't work. Jw's controls don't come up but it throws no errors and chrome is showing all the files are loading fine.

The live server is just a git pull of what ever has been pushed from the test server so they should be identical code.

I'm really confused by this since it's all client side code in regards to the actual playing of the video... why is it acting differently on one domain and not the other? I've tried it with and without the jw license code and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out, after hours of banging my head against a wall; it turns out GIT is not super awesome for saving binary data such as SWF (which jwplayer uses for flash video display for rtmp streams!)

Answer: GIT was corrupting the jwplayer.flash.swf

Solution: Add .swf to git ignore list and don't store binary data in the repo! or add .swf binary to your.gitattributes